# Android: An array of arrays and a listview

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I've read a java tutorial explaining an "array of arrays" with something similar to coordinates. For instance,

```
mainArray [0] [0] = "arrayA";
mainArray [0] [1] = 1;
mainArray [0] [2] = 2;
mainArray [1] [0] = "arrayB";
mainArray [1] [1] = 1;
```

Is it plausable to populate a listview using this type of array in android (using the first set of numbers and not the subset)? I haven't had the chance to try it yet.

Comment: you can see the following which is may help you.
Stackoverflow existing problem and solution. [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952495/how-to-create-multidimensional-array) and [Link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979122/multidimensional-array-in-java) Two dimesional array in java. [Link1](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/arrayexamples/two.shtml) and [link 2](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1162)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You have to write a custom `ListAdapter` preferable extending `ArrayAdapter`.

Look at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep looking through this code and studying it. Other custom array adapter codes I've seen are close to what im looking for but alot more difficult to understand without the notes.

Answer (score 0):

A better option would be to define a "coordinates" object and then make an array or list of those objects.  Then use that to populate your ListView.

Comment: Are you referring to the array of arrays?  If not, I don't quite understand.